# Как сделать чтобы у slick-slide не было width=0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider-slick.js

подскажите пожалуйста, делаю слайдер, всего на сайте будет 4 разных слайдера на slick slider, как правильно их инициализровать ? И тут с 4 слайдером возникла проблема, он состоит из 2 блоков и показывает 1 слайд. В блоке картинки, при загрузке сайлдера, блок имеет ширину 0 и ломается и при прокрутке слайдов появлется ширина и все ок. Как пофиксить эту проблему ?

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
         $('.slider-countries').slick({
           slidesToShow: 1,
           slidesToScroll: 1,
           dots: true,
           arrows: false,
           infinite: true,
         });
     });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
         $('.slider-countries').slick({
           slidesToShow: 1,
           width: 330,
           slidesToScroll: 1,
           dots: true,
           arrows: false,
           infinite: true,
         });
     });
```

Comment: К сожелнию не работает. Работает вариант только variableWidth: true и ширину для слайдеров. Но получется полная ерунда. Я не понимаю почему ширину не вытсавляет, а как только листаешь слайдр сразу ширина появляется ?

Comment: @Алексей В вопрос выложите полностью код слайдера (html, CSS, JS)